# AdMob bannerView not showing after following the docs

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm trying to show ads in my app, and I have chosen AdMob. I have done everything as they wrote in the docs.

I added this to the `AppDelegate`:

```
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
```

I also added this code to the `viewDidLoad`:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpView()
        
    adBannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    adBannerView.rootViewController = self
    adBannerView.load(GADRequest())
}
```

The `adBannerView` is a `UIView` in `main.storyboard` that has `GADBannerView` as subclass (also, it's connected via `@IBOutlet`.)
But, the ad isn't showing in the simulator. I get this error message every so often (prob when it refreshes)

```
2020-10-05 19:36:47.683540+0200 Learn Chemistry[38879:1067024] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-10-05 19:36:47.683687+0200 Learn Chemistry[38879:1067024] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-10-05 19:36:50.123788+0200 Learn Chemistry[38879:1067024] [Process] 0x7fd3fe019420 - [pageProxyID=31, webPageID=32, PID=39055] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID = 3, domain = NSURLErrorDomain, code = -1200
2020-10-05 19:36:50.164032+0200 Learn Chemistry[38879:1067024] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}>
2020-10-05 19:36:50.164192+0200 Learn Chemistry[38879:1067024] [ProcessSuspension] 0x147efe1c0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID 39055, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}
2020-10-05 19:36:50.174754+0200 Learn Chemistry[38879:1067024] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
2020-10-05 19:36:50.174900+0200 Learn Chemistry[38879:1067024] [ProcessSuspension] 0x147efe240 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID 39055, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}
2020-10-05 19:37:20.127313+0200 Learn Chemistry[38879:1067024] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
```

Is there anything I did wrong?

thank you.

BSM

Comment: You need to make sure you have the Google plist in your project, and you should be using the test ad while your app is in development. You do not want adUnitId to display real adds while testing because if you click on them you will get suspended. It also takes sometime to get you account verified with the new app. Also the error log doesnt mention anything about Admob unless i missed soemthing.

Comment: @LucasDahl where can I find that `PList` ?
I know that when I would add firebase to a project, I would get that as a step to download. But it didn't was the case by adMob

Comment: Im sorry I was mistaken with using Firebase. What you do have to do is add GADApplicationIdentifier in your plist file.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @LucasDahl but that worked! thx a ton!

Comment: not a problem! Glad it helped!

Comment: @BSM what "worked" for you? I do have the same issue right now. Did you add firebase and the Google plist or did you "just use" the test ads which made it work? Would be cool if you answer your question with what actually worked.

Comment: @bruno bieri, I would love to answer my own question, but I did somethings, and I couldn't recall what till today what did it. If I find it I will post it here. ]